# Jitters when setting scroll on window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll, jquery-events

EDIT:

I figured out the cause of the issue.  When you scroll with the scrollbar, and then programmatically set the scroll, the scrollbar moves, which causes the browser to recalculate the scroll position based on the position of the mouse relative to the new scrollbar position.  Now I'm looking for a solution.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PGYuMuGrN8&feature=youtube_gdata_player) is a Youtube video of the problem using code from one of the answers below.

ORIGINAL POST:

Im trying to achieve an effect where the window scrolls in increments equal to the size of elements in a grid, so that the scrolling looks smooth.  The elements are 40px square, with 4px of padding, so I'm trying to scroll the page in increments of 44px.  I've written some code, and it works great when the page scrolls vertically.  I've got the exact same operation (or so I think) set up for horizontal scrolling, but when I scroll horizontally, the page jitters back and forth.  I've tried debugging it, and it seems like the window scroll left gets set to some seemingly random value every second or third time the scroll handler is invoked.

Here is the code (and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftyp/YJ8n3/1/)):

```
$(function(){

    // Here is the scroll function in question

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var lastScrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();

        return function(){
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
            var yDir = scrollTop - lastScrollTop > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            var xDir = scrollLeft - lastScrollLeft > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            $(this).scrollTop(~yDir ? scrollTop + ((44 - ((scrollTop + 44) % 44))) : scrollTop - (scrollTop % 44));
            $(this).scrollLeft(~xDir ? scrollLeft + ((44 - ((scrollLeft + 44) % 44))) : scrollLeft - (scrollLeft % 44));
            scrollTop = lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            scrollLeft = lastScrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
        }
    }());
});
```

EDIT:

I'm testing this in Chrome 26.0.1410.65 btw.

EDIT:

The problem occurs with vertical scrolling too, but only when using the scrollbar, not the mousewheel.

Comment: this doesn't help your case at all but here's a fun note: you've created an optical illusion in your fiddle, if you look at the corners it seems to create little blue dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the cause of the issue as stated at the top of the question, I don't think there is a direct solution to this issue using the method in the code.  The solution I ended up using was to implement a sort of virtual scrolling.  I put the element to be scrolled into a 'viewport' div with a fixed position filling the window area.  Then I expanded the window size using a 'scrollTarget' div, and scrolled the viewport in increments of 44 based on the scroll position of the window. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftyp/YJ8n3/18/).

### Javascript

```
$(function(){

    // Here is the scroll function in question

    $(this).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
        $('#viewport').scrollTop(scrollTop - (scrollTop % 44));
        $('#viewport').scrollLeft(scrollLeft - (scrollLeft % 44));
    });


    // Generates the grid, ignore this part

    for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
        var row = $('<div></div>').addClass('row').appendTo('#viewport');
        for(var j=0; j<50; j++)
            $('<span></span>').appendTo(row).addClass('cell').text(50*i+j);
    }

    $('#scrollTarget').height((50 * 44) + 48)
        .width((50 * 44) + 48);
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="viewport"></div>
<div id="scrollTarget"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#viewport{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#scrollTarget{
    position:absolute;
}

.row{
    height:44px;
    width:2204px;
}

.row:first-child{
    height:40px;
}

.cell{
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
    background-color:#859DE1;
    color:#0F1219;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.row:first-child .cell{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where `scrollTop - lastScrollTop` and `scrollLeft - lastScrollLeft`  are zero and is causing problems in your logic.

See these two lines

```
var yDir = scrollTop - lastScrollTop > 0 ? 1 : -1;
var xDir = scrollLeft - lastScrollLeft > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

Say the difference is > 0, your `xDir` variable will have 1 and you set scrollLeft to `scrollTop + ((44 - ((scrollTop + 44) % 44))`.

Next iteration difference is 0, your `xDir` variable will have -1 and you will now use  `scrollLeft - (scrollLeft % 44))`. These two equations do not evaluate to the same even though the scroll position didn't changed.

Try this.

```
$(function(){

    // Here is the scroll function in question

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastScrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
        var lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        return function(){
            var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (lastScrollLeft !== scrollLeft) {
                lastScrollLeft = scrollLeft - (scrollLeft % 44);
                $(this).scrollLeft(lastScrollLeft);               
            } 

            if (lastScrollTop !== scrollTop) {
                lastScrollTop = scrollTop - (scrollTop % 44);
                $(this).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);   
            }

       }
    }());

    // Generates the grid, ignore this part

    for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
        var row = $('<div></div>').addClass('row').appendTo('body');
        for(var j=0; j<50; j++)
            $('<span></span>').appendTo(row).addClass('cell').text(50*i+j);
    }
});
```

Comment: If scroll difference is zero, then it just sets the scroll top equal to itself, and it has no effect.

Comment: Updated answer, too much for a comment.

Comment: Well, this answer worked well in firefox but is really awfull in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/7Xzu6/

Comment: When you say it worked fine...are you using the mousewheel or the scrollbar?

Comment: Look closely when you scroll with the scrollbar, you still see the jitter.

Comment: I'm using the scrollbar and I don't see any jitter. I'm using firefox 20.1 on windows. IE is another story, it's worse than the original.

Comment: Like I said in the question I'm using chrome...and you see less of a jitter, but its still there.